# If the the wavefunction is even or odd (symmetric or antisymmetric )about an point could we say that the expectation value of momentum is zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I've come across a wavefunction  $$\psi(x)=xe^{-\left(x\right)^2}$$ which is an odd function.

The expectation value is said to be zero . I don't know any good physical interpretation for why the expectation of momentum is zero by just looking at a function (not sure if there is one). But if there is, could I say that since the probability of the the particle to be on the left and right of $x=0$ are equal and probability at $x = a$ or $x = -a$ is also equal where $a$ is any positive value, then since the probability is symmetric then and also independent of time then expectation value of momentum is zero. Is this a valid interpretation?

Comment: I suspect you mean $\exp[ -x^2]$, not $\exp[(-x)^2]$, but I didn't change it in case you so mean the latter.

Comment: You where right , i made a mistake. My apologies, not used to writing in mathjax as of yet . I'll correct it at the earliest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of your question is a little more general than the example you provide.

Consider for instance wavefunctions of the form $\psi_n(x)\sim e^{-(x-a)^2/2}H_n(x-a)$.  These functions are even or odd about $x=a$.  The probability densities $\vert\psi_n(x)\vert^2$ are symmetrical about $x=a$ and $\langle x\rangle=a$ in this case, and a parity argument holds but about $x=a$.  Alternatively, the parity argument can be repeated to conclude that $\langle x-a\rangle=0$.

One can get insight into $\langle p\rangle$ in two ways.  If the wavefunction is simple, say $\psi_n(x)$ again, then 
$$
\langle p\rangle =\int dx \psi_n(x)\left(-i\hbar \psi'_n(x)\right)
=-i\hbar \int dx \psi_n(x)\psi'_n(x)
$$
must be $0$ since the average value of the momentum must be real wheras the integral is necessarily purely imaginary.

However,  consider now the more complicated 
$$\phi(x)=\sum_k c_k \psi_k(x)
$$ 
with again
$\psi_k(x)\sim e^{-(x-a)^2/2}H_n(x-a)$ but some $c_k$'s complex.

The previous argument about the reality of the wavefunction and its derivative does not immediately apply but  $\langle p\rangle$ is again $0$.  To see this, recall that $p=m\dot{x}$ so that
$$
\langle p\rangle = m \frac{d}{dt}\langle x\rangle =  m \frac{d}{dt}\int x \phi(x)^* \phi(x)
$$
Here, since $\phi(x)$ does not depend on $t$, $\langle \dot{x}\rangle=0$.
  This last argument shows in fact that the average momentum for a time-independent probability distribution must be $0$, which makes sense since non-zero momentum implies the particle changes position in time, which in turn implies that the probability density ought to change in time to reflect the motion of the particle.  Of course if you use
$$
\Psi(x,t)=\sum_k c_k \psi_k(x)e^{-iE_kt/\hbar}
$$
then $\Psi(x,t)^* \Psi(x,t)$ will be time-dependent and $\langle p\rangle \ne 0$.

Answer (score 5):

The mean momentum is $-i\hbar\int dx\psi^\ast\psi'$. If $\psi$ is real with a definite parity, the integrand is odd so the mean momentum is zero.